# export file from table to excel using php

Tags: php, excel

hi im a newbie in programming and im using php. below is my code for .xls. i have one form where i have three buttons the add search and "save to excel". and also i have a table where my output for add button will be shown and that was connected to my database. now my problem is when i click the button "save to excel", the whole data in my form appear to the excel. what i want is that the table in my form will be only save in my excel. not the whole data in my form. if i can only post the image here you probably might understand me clearly. :( . but please i need some help. :( .. thanks

```
if (isset($_POST['download']))
{
$file="document_name" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");// file extension name
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What are you struggling with?

Comment: how will i declare in my codes that the only thing that it will save to excel is the data in the table of my form.

Comment: if you want to see the image i can show it to you. just give me your email and ill send it to you. :)

Comment: You can post images on SO

Comment: i tried it earlier but i need to have 10 reputation to be able for me to post images.

Answer (score -1):

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=line_utilization_report.xls ");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

Comment: WAT!?! How many different (and all incorrect) content types? You should only ever have a single content-type, and the correct content type for an Excel BIFF (.xls) file is `application/vnd.ms-excel`

Comment: And it still doesn't answer the OP's question of how to actually generate the Excel file to download - or is this advocacy of PHP's automagic extension to extract selected elements from a full page of HTML markup and write it to an Excel BIFF format file?